# How can I fix robotic distortion from an audio track?

Tags: noise, compression, audio-restoration

First of all I apologize if the title doesn't make any sense. I lack the vocabulary to describe the issue that I have with an audio track I'm trying to fix or at least make a little better.

This is an excerpt from the [*damaged* audio](http://victmo.com/dropbox/robotic.wav) (let's call it *robotic*) and this the [original audio](http://victmo.com/dropbox/normal.wav) (lets call it *normal*).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a name to describe this type of distortion?
2. How can I fix (or reduce the distortion from) the *robotic audio* and make it sound more like the *normal audio*?

Comment: Are you sure it is distortion ? sounds to me more like a delay than a distortion ?!

Comment: It does sound more like a set of effects than plain echo. What caused this?

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you use the original audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Buffer underrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_underrun) might have caused that distortion to the audio.

Buffer values can be increased in the audio driver section of the software or DAW you're using so that the issue disappears when exporting.

There's no easy fix to samples exported with digital artifacts but you can treat them as intermittent noises or clicks and use restoration software like iZotope RX to clean it up a little bit.

Comment: Do you know of any alternative to iZotope RX? This is for a personal thing and in this case, it's not worth paying for a license. Thanks!